# Setting Max. File Size for File Uploads Returns Blank Page After Upload

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, filesize

**UPDATE**: I've cleaned up my form and image validation up a bit. I ditched the original approach of finding the image's extension and went ahead by first validating that the uploaded file was an image using getimagesize(). From there, I made sure the image was a jpg or .jpeg by grabbing the extension using pathinfo() and matching it with an array that contained jpg and jpeg.

I then made sure the file was uploaded successfully and then moved successfully from the temporary location to my location I set. The next step was to create the new image using "imagecreatefromjpeg" but I received the error

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 13056 bytes) in FILENAME.php on line 48

This is where I'm confused because the image I was attempting to upload is well under my max file size of 2MB (image is 410k). Not quite sure why it's going over the 32MB memory limit that my server is at.

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['uploadImage'])){

    //  set variables for uploaded file
    $uploadTempPath = $_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'];
    $uploadSize = $_FILES['uploadFile']['size'];
    $uploadLimit = 2097152; /* 2mb max file size */
    $uploadName = strtolower($_FILES['uploadFile']['name']);    // grab upload filename and lowercase the extension (.JPG -> .jpg)

    //  check if something was uploaded
    if (empty($uploadTempPath)){
        echo '<script language="JavaScript">';
        echo 'alert("You did not upload anything!!")';
        echo '</script>'; 
        $errors .= 'You did not upload an image <br>';
    }

    // if all required fields were filled and a file was actually selected to upload
    if (empty($errors)) :

        //  1A.  Check that file uplaoded is a valid image
        if ( getimagesize($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name']) ) :

            //  2B.  Verify that image extension was a jpg or jpeg
            $imgExt = pathinfo( $_FILES['uploadFile']['name'] , PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
            $validExt = array( 'jpg', 'jpeg' );
            if ( in_array($imgExt, $validExt) ) :

                //  3A.  Make sure image was uploaded successfully
                if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'])) :

                    $uploadPath = 'images/uploads/';
                    $imgWidth = '620';
                    $imgFilename = pathinfo( $_FILES['uploadFile']['name'] , PATHINFO_BASENAME );
                    $newPath = $uploadPath . $imgFilename;

                    //  4A.  Move uploaded file from temporary path to new path
                    if(move_uploaded_file ($uploadTempPath , $newPath)) :

                        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($newPath);

                        // PRINT OUT INFORMATION IF ALL IS CORRECT SO FAR
                        echo 'File was moved <br>'; 
                        echo 'Maximum file size: ' . $uploadLimit . '<br>';
                        echo 'Uploaded file size: ' . $uploadSize . '<br>';
                        echo 'Filename: ' . $imgFilename . '<br>';
                        echo 'New Path: ' . $newPath . '<br>';
                        echo 'File extension: ' . pathinfo($_FILES['uploadFile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION) . '<br>';

                    //  4B.  Image was not successful in being moved
                    else : 

                        echo 'Image was NOT moved! <br>'; 

                    endif; //  END 4

                //  3B.  Image was not uploaded.. 
                else :

                    // beware of an ATTACK!
                    echo 'Image was not uploaded. <br>';

                endif; //  END 3

            //  2B.  File was not a jpg or jpeg 
            else :

                echo '<script language="JavaScript">';
                echo 'alert("Your image is not a jpeg! Its a ' . pathinfo($_FILES['uploadFile']['name'] , PATHINFO_EXTENSION) . '")';
                echo '</script>'; 
                $errors .= 'NOT A JPEG! <br>';

            endif; //  END 2

        //  1B.  File uploaded was not a valid image
        else :

            echo '<script language="JavaScript">';
            echo 'alert("Invalid Image!")';
            echo '</script>'; 
            $errors .= 'The file you uploaded is not a valid image file <br>';

        endif; //  END 1

    endif; // endif empty errors

}   

?>
```

Comment: Please turn on errors: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors' , 1);` than post it in your question, this might be some error from the runtime.

Comment: 1) You're not halting the script if there are errors, so you'll proceed to resizing no matter what. 2) Your image validation is very poor

Comment: Could you point line 40 in your submit.php ?

Comment: Line 40: if ( preg_match ('/[.](jpg)|(jpeg)$/' , $uploadNewName )) { $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadNewPath . $uploadNewName); }

Comment: You seem to exhaust all available memory here :)

Answer (score 0):

this is because the entire file is going in to the cache as variable.
try to upload smaller image and you will see that it is working fine.

well, you have to increase the memory size. 
but this is something that you should think twice before doing it (security).

```
ini_set("memory_limit","350M");// or any thing you want here

//run the script here...

ini_set("memory_limit","128M");//back to normal
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding my comment, you're not stopping your script execution if you encounter an error like max file size. Don't rely to the html form to actually stop the uploading (which fails silently, by the way) in case of bigger images than allowed. And in your php, you just create an error index, but you go on with your image manipulation nonetheless.

Also, your image validation is very poor, for a couple of reasons:

1) **preg matching if it contains the extension is a VERY POOR validation**, if none at all.

Try uploading shell.php.jpg and you'll see why ;) One of the best method to check if an image is a valid one is to use [**getimagesize()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php), which gives you an array of 7 elements with many useful informations, besides telling you that the image is a true image.
What if I save a jpg image with a png extension? I'll trick your script to look for a png, while instead it being a jpg. That will break your imagecreate* function easily.

2)**Your way to get an extension is faulty,** a file like my.picture.jpg will just broke it easily.

You can use [**pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to get that information; this function will get also a correct filename, dirpath, etc and its more reliable than any homebrew stripping, stroposing and whatnot

3) PNGs and GIFs should require addictional treatment, like [**saving the alpha channel**](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php); you'll lose your images transparencies like this.

To extend your memory limit, use `ini_set("memory_limit","VALUE HERE")`, as suggested. But keep in mind that usually that's not an issue in case of not big images, so there's something else which is causing trouble. If you mend the code there, you won't even need to use this "hack"; besides, extending it does mean you allocate more resources (than should be alocated), and your script might not fail, but **that doesnt mean your script is *better***

Oh, another one: are you by chance storing the image inside the database, as a blob field? (it's not clear what are you doing with your INSERT statement). I suggest just saving the path to a varchar in your DB, for a number of reason (performance, data integrity, etc) inserting the whole binaries of an image in a db field is not the best strategy.

Comment: Thanks, Damien. I will clean up the validation and look into getimagesize() and pathfile()

Comment: If I upload a shell script called `shellfile.picture.png.jpg` I'll make your script loose it's mind, so yeah, strongening your validation is the first step.

Answer (score 0):

First of all let's fix some minor bugs: you should escape period in filename regex to match actually period; then you should check and create $uploadNewPath dir before yor're actually using it. And you can try to use imagecreatefromX on tmp files without actually moving them to new location 'cause you trying to overwrite them with new resized image.